# Why does Java shows extra values after float calculation?

Tags: java, math

I have a very simple piece of code below which I think gives the wrong result from a user's perspective.

```
package com.test.sample;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float c,d;

        c = (float) 12.47;
        d = (float) 12.44;
        d = c - d;

        System.out.println("Hello the calculated value of a=" + d);
    }

}
```

The output is 
`Hello the calculated value of a=0.030000687`

But I want `a=0.030000000` which is the perfect value.

Comment: Welcome to the wonders of floating point numbers! And if you're really interested, you should read this: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: float is nearest possible representation in binary... it can't be exact, so imperfection. The accumulating error finally doomed The Matrix, you know.

Comment: Look [Machine Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Machine_precision) it's not Java specific.

Comment: @Fred, that's also the same link I provided.

Comment: Oh sorry, when I made the comment I did not see any answers.

Comment: Do you need the high precision calulation or do you just need a nice output? (and since you asked that question, the answer is clear): `System.out.format("Hello the calculated value of a=%.5f\n", d)` (5 is the number of digits after the decimal point)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Floating point arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), what developers should know.

The JVM implements the [IEEE-754 1985 floating point standard](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-1996/jw-10-hood.html) and it has its [accuracy problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) (since floating point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers).

If you seek accuracy, use `java.math.BigDecimal` object instead.

---

**Update:** This is how I took your example and used `BigDecimal` to achieve your **expected** result:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public class BigDecimalTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(12.47f));
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(12.44f));
        BigDecimal c = a.subtract(b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: So whats the solution for this ??

Comment: +1 for a solution. Many people just go 'floating point is inaccurate, read this'

Comment: @Fred, true, hence why we are here. To provide solution (and get better rep) :-)

Comment: Hey i did this change 
public static void main(String[] args) {
float c,d;
c=(float)12.47;
d=(float)12.44;
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(12.47);
BigDecimal  b = new BigDecimal(12.44);
b= a.subtract(b);
System.out.println(" Now BigDecimal vlue ==" +b);
}

But the output
 Now BigDecimal vlue ==0.0300000000000011368683772161602973937988281250000

Comment: @vins, see my updated post with source code. It gives me an output of `0.03` **exactly**.