# Show maximum X digits after the dot

Tags: java, android, string, string-formatting

I want to show only 7 digits after the dot and I have an issue if the number contain less then 7 digits, for some reason it is padded with extra digits.

I tried with `DecimalFormat("##.#######").format(float value)` and `String.format("%.07f", float value)`

Here are examples:

- 4.275 is present as 4.275001
- 1 is present as 1.0000000 using `String.format` (present right using `DecimalFormat`).

How can I show maximum X digits after the dot, without padding the number?

**EDIT**

here is code example:

```
TextView tvDec = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDecimal);
TextView tvStringFormat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStringFormat);
float num = 4.275f;
String finalNum = new DecimalFormat("##.#######").format(Float.valueOf(num));
tvDec.setText(finalNum);
finalNum = String.format("%.07f", Float.valueOf(num));
tvStringFormat.setText(finalNum);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: if input is `4.275 ` what output you expect?

Comment: @Rustam 4.275; I'm want MAX 7 digits after the dot

Comment: `4.275` is formatted as `4.275` using your decimalformat. You probably have a slightly different value than you think.

Comment: Are you using `float` or `double` by the way? This affects how soon you will run into [exact floating-point representation problems](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). The decimalformat above works fine for `4.275` as `double`, but not for `float` since the precision isn't enough.

Comment: @Keppil - Thank you! So there is nothing to do, just to write a method by my self to present this right?

Comment: @AsfK: You can either switch to `double` if that is enough for you, or to `BigDecimal` to be certain that the computer's representation is correct. Then your `DecimalFormat` should work for all values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the number 4.275 cannot be represented as a float, 4.275f represents indeed the number 4.275000095367431640625.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952368/why-does-java-shows-extra-values-after-float-calculation) explains it you should use:

```
float val = 4.275f;
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(val).setScale(7, RoundingMode.DOWN).stripTrailingZeros().toString());
```

Comment: I did not understand first that you wanted to get 4.275. I've added the `stripTrailingZeros()`.

Comment: `new BigDecimal(float)` is not precise. You could use `new BigDecimal(String)` for example to get the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like

```
new BigDecimal(number).setScale(7, RoundingMode.CEILING).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got 4.2750001 using your suggestion

Comment: Ok then your problem is that you have issues with your floating point just as Xavier mentions